# html image click event to load image in a conditional way

Tags: javascript, html, image, onclick

i have added four image in html and i want the image to load another image in a placeholder when the image is clicked. and if the 1st image is clicked it load image a and if another image is clicked they will load another image after one click on any of these four images the link wants to be disabled i have use this code but it doesn't work please help me to make this happen thanks in advance..

```html
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('aswT'). src='right.gif' ;">    
        <img src="m.jpg" id="right" /></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('aswT'). src='wrong.gif' ;">    
        <img src="e.jpg" id="wrong" /></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('aswT'). src='wrong.gif' ;">    
        <img src="o.jpg" id="wrong" /></a>
        <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('aswT'). src='wrong.gif' ;">    
        <img src="n.jpg" id="wrong" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbeZPp

```js
function changeImage(arg) {
if( document.getElementById('imagePlaceholder').src ==  arg.target.src) {
document.getElementById('imagePlaceholder').src =  "http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png";
} else {
document.getElementById('imagePlaceholder').src =  arg.target.src;
}
}
```

```css
#imageLinks a img {width:100px;height:100px;margin:15px;}
#imagePlaceholder {width:300px;height:300px;margin:15px;}
```

```html
<img id="imagePlaceholder" src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2014/04/10/11752526/gI_134971_best-image-web-hosting.png" />
<div id="imageLinks">
  <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(event);"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1239356116/TwitterBirdCool_400x400.JPG" /></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(event);"><img src="http://www.kampfkunst-centrum.de/assets/images/Cool-Kids.jpg" /></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="changeImage(event);"><img src="http://img02.deviantart.net/9dd3/i/2012/345/e/7/cool_and_wild_cat_by_design_by_humans-d5nqtl8.jpg" id="wrong" /></a><a href="#" onclick="changeImage(event);"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/579982585138405378/daYox4Wy.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: thx Jin but i have to load another image in the place holder just like if the user select one image from those four it want to load that the image is right is right or wrong and the user have only one chance to click

Comment: just like this but the big placeholder will load that, the clicked image is right or wrong as an image. and the user can click only one image from the four images

Comment: so you want to "lock" the other images? and only one is the right one, right? it should do something particular when is clicked the right image or not?